# IEnumerable<int> Requires also the Non generic IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ienumerable

3 questions :

1) why does the out put is taken from the **NON** generic function ?

2) why do I **have** to implement ALSO the NON generic function ?

3) What do I need to do if i want to see the Generic function output ( the int's) ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The `foreach` keyword does not require the collection to implement `IEnumerable` at all; rather, it will call any defined `GetEnumerator` methods.
2. `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable` for compatibility reasons.
3. You should implement `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` explicitly and have the normal method return `IEnumerator<T>`.

If the class has a normal `GetEnumerator()` method (as opposed to an explicit interface implementation), the compiler will call it.
The spec says:

> - Otherwise, determine whether the type X has an appropriate GetEnumerator method:
>
>   - Perform member lookup on the type X with identifier GetEnumerator and no type arguments. If the member lookup does not produce a match,
>       or it produces an ambiguity, or produces a match that is not a method
>       group, check for an enumerable interface as described below. It is
>       recommended that a warning be issued if member lookup produces
>       anything except a method group or no match.
>   - Perform overload resolution using the resulting method group and an empty argument list. If overload resolution results in no
>       applicable methods, results in an ambiguity, or results in a single
>       best method but that method is either static or not public, check for
>       an enumerable interface as described below. It is recommended that a
>       warning be issued if overload resolution produces anything except an
>       unambiguous public instance method or no applicable methods.
>   - [...]
> - Otherwise, check for an enumerable interface:

Comment: Additional reading: [Following the pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

1) The output is taken from the non generic function because it is defined implicitly (and the generic function is defined explicitly).

2) `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so any type inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>` also has to implement the members of `IEnumerable`

3) Make the generic definition implicit and the non-generic definition explicit, e.g.

```
public class Class1 : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield return 4;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that you can return the generic enumerator from the non-generic method because `IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement both, since `IEnumerable<T>` is derived from `IEnumerable`. To call an explicitly implemented method you need to cast to that interface.

But usually you implement the non generic method explicitly and the generic method implicitly. That way `foreach` will use the generic method. `foreach` uses the `GetEnumerator()` method on the type of the collection, and only falls back to the interface methods if this method is not present.

The typical implementation is:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
   ...
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  return GetEnumerator();//Forward to strongly typed version
}
```

Comment: `return GetEnumerator();//Fo` has error : **iterator can not contain return statement ...**

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Get rid of the `yield`s.